# Flatpickr uses different native calendar in mobile browser and in webview (IOS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webview, flatpickr

When I try to open my app that uses **vue-flatpickr-component** in a browser on my iphone I get a different native calendar than the one I get when I open the app in webview.

On android the calendars are the same in both cases.

What causes this? Can I somehow affect this? Is there some way I can debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/) of Flatpickr

You will find the option `disableMobile`.

**disableMobile information:**

Set disableMobile to true to always use the non-native picker.
By default, flatpickr utilizes native datetime widgets unless certain options (disable) are used.